# Find files interactively with a snippet

Tags: helm, yasnippet

It should be nice to write yasnippets, which ask for filepath interactively using helm, predefining starting directory should be fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list is always the same you should be able to use the `yasnippet-choose-value` function as described in the [manual](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-8).

You could also do a snippet like this if you want the search through all of the files like you would when opening any file normally

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: test
# key: test
# --
My File: ${1:$$(unless yas-modified-p (completing-read "File: " 'read-file-name-internal))}
```

If you have any questions or it doesn't work perfectly just let me know!

**EDIT:**

A function to use a predefined directory:

```
(defun my-yas-insert-file-name (dir)
  "Insert absolute path inside yassnipets from given directory"
  (let ((default-directory dir))
    (unless yas-modified-p
      (expand-file-name (completing-read "File: " 'read-file-name-internal)))))
```

Comment: Thanks :) . I extended the answer with a small function based on your code with the capability to predefine a directory inside the snippets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to browse through your directories, you should rather define the snippet like this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: test
# key: test
# --
My File: `(insert (file-relative-name (read-file-name "") (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))`
```

In this example, the path is chosen relative to the buffer where the snippet was invoked.

Note that `yasnippet` will throw a warning because `insert` is being used. To suppress it, add the following to your `init.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'warning-suppress-types '(yasnippet backquote-change))
```

Comment: Instead of suppressing the warning, replace ```My file:`(insert ...)` ``` with```My file:`...` ```. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/yasnippet-truncates-clipboard-contents for more examples.

Comment: @npostavs It's true. Thanks for pointing this out!