# yasnippet truncates clipboard contents

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet

I have a yasnippet that is intended to create a footnote in org-mode format and automatically insert the contents of the clipboard.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: footnote
# key: fn 
# --
[fn:: `(clipboard-yank)`]
```

This worked correctly until this week. Desired output is this:

```
[fn:: foo]
```

But now when I do it, it truncates the contents and adds a Y, such that when the clipboard contains `foo`, entering `fn <TAB>` results in this output:

```
[fn:: ooY]
```

## UPDATE/CLARIFICATION

My yasnippet for org-mode footnotes actually uses not `clipboard-yank` but my own custom function [pasteboard-paste-no-spaces](https://github.com/incandescentman/Emacs-Settings/blob/master/gnu-emacs-startup.org#pasteboard-paste-no-spaces).

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: footnote
# key: fn 
# --
[fn:: `(pasteboard-paste-no-spaces)`]
```

For simplicity, I mentioned `clipboard-yank` since I tested it and it has the same problem. But since I use a custom function, switching to `current-kill` won't work for me.

Here's `pasteboard-paste-no-spaces`:

```
(defun pasteboard-paste-no-spaces ()
  "Paste from OS X system pasteboard via `pbpaste' to point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (point))
    (end (if mark-active
         (mark)
           (point))))
    (shell-command-on-region start end
                 "pbpaste | perl -p -e 's/\r$//' | tr '\r' '\n'"
                 nil t)
    (save-excursion
      )))
```

## UPDATE #2

Thanks for all the help. I'm having the same problem with [tiny-expand](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny/blob/master/tiny.el). I tried using the `(with-temp-buffer)` approach you suggested to create a new function `yas/tiny-expand`, but it doesn't work:

```
(defun yas/tiny-expand (&rest args)
 "Return the string that `tiny-expand' would insert."
 (with-temp-buffer
 (apply #'tiny-expand args) 
 (buffer-string)))
```

Here is the relevant yasnippet where I tried to use `(with-temp-buffer)`: https://gist.github.com/5a799834ddf948ce65a7def95a834401

Here's the original version:
https://gist.github.com/1c947de20a1b7790d04d69ac39884f22

Comment: You want `(apply #'tiny-expand args)` not `(apply #'yas/tiny-expand args)`, the latter would be infinite recursion.

Comment: Fixed. But even without the infinite recursion, `yas/tiny-expand` still doesn't expand.

Comment: I don't understand what `tiny-expand` is supposed to do: when I do `M-x tiny-expand` nothing happens.

Comment: @npostavs Answer/explanation: https://gist.github.com/0eb35626765f05abd3e029c35f82db26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `current-kill` instead of `clipboard-yank` because the latter works by side-effect.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: footnote
# key: fn 
# --
[fn:: `(current-kill 0)`]
```

---

> I'm actually not using `clipboard-yank` but my own custom function `pasteboard-paste-no-spaces`

You would need to modify your custom function to return a string value instead of inserting it directly, something like:

```el
(defun pasteboard-without-spaces ()
  "Return content of OS X system pasteboard via `pbpaste'."
  (shell-command-to-string "pbpaste | perl -p -e 's/\r$//' | tr '\r' '\n'"))
```

---

> I seem to be getting the same error with [...] `org-insert-time-stamp`

That function is more problematic since it weaves together inserting the string with generating it.  You can run it in a temp buffer to make it behave better:

```el
(defun yas/org-get-time-stamp (&rest args)
  "Return the string that `org-insert-time-stamp' would insert."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (apply #'org-insert-time-stamp args)
    (buffer-string)))
```

You can apply this trick to any function that inserts content directly to the buffer.

---

> I'm having the same problem with [tiny-expand](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny/blob/master/tiny.el).

This functions also wants to read and delete other text in the buffer, to make it safe the text should be passed as a string instead:

```el
(defun yas/tiny-expand (str)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert str)
    (goto-char (point-max)) ; tiny-expand works on text preceding point
    (tiny-expand)
    (buffer-string)))
```

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: jdw
# key: jdw
# --

* week of `(yas/org-get-time-stamp (current-time))` [0%] 
*** WEEKLIES - week of `(yas/org-get-time-stamp (current-time))` 
***** TODO review weeklies
***** TODO $0

*** DAILIES - week of `(yas/org-get-time-stamp (current-time))` 
`(yas/tiny-expand "m0\\n9|\\n***** COMMITTED <%(date \"today\" x)> [0%%]\\n******* TODO wake up 8:30am\\n SCHEDULED: <%(date \"today\" x) 8:30am>\\n******* TODO blue light \\n SCHEDULED: <%(date \"today\" x) 8:31am>\\n******* TODO meditate \\n SCHEDULED: <%(date \"today\" x) 8:45am>\\n******* TODO write Wise Mind form or LIFE form\\n SCHEDULED: <%(date \"today\" x) 9:00am> \\n******* TODO disable Internet\\n SCHEDULED: <%(date \"today\" x) 9:15am> \\n******* TODO morning pages at a café or at The Writers' Room \\n SCHEDULED: <%(date \"today\" x) 9:45am>\\n******* TODO go straight to The Writers' Room\\n SCHEDULED: <%(date \"today\" x) 10:00am>\\n******* TODO review weeklies and calibrate with dailies \\n******* TODO submit dailies to Erika \\n DEADLINE: <%(date \"today\" x) 2:00pm> \\n******* TODO work on book 3 hours \\n******* TODO two lines of poetry \\n DEADLINE: <%(date \"today\" x) 8:00pm> \\n******* TODO lights out by 12:30am\\n SCHEDULED: <%(date \"today\" x) 11:59pm> \\n\\n")`
```

Note that the string param needs to be escaped for the Lisp reader (an easy way to do this quickly is to use `paredit-doublequote`).

---

If you don't feel like changing all your snippets right now, the latest release, 0.10.0 (available from MELPA stable and GNU ELPA), will work with your original snippet.  I plan to temporarily (i.e. at least until release 0.11.0) back out the change that breaks this and just issue a warning for snippets that do insertion by side-effect.  See also [yasnippet issue #710](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/710).

Comment: I'm actually not using `clipboard-yank` but my own custom function `pasteboard-paste-no-spaces`. For simplicity, I avoided trying to explain a complicated custom function in the question since this also happens with `clipboard-yank`. But switching to `current-kill` won't work for me. I added details in the question.

Comment: @incandescentman: updated for your custom paste function.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error with this snippet: `(let ((x (org-insert-time-stamp (current-time)))))`. How would I fix this one? https://gist.github.com/2e49d06c84cbcb92c7e6bc0a11759b3b

Comment: @incandescentman wrap in `with-temp-buffer`, see edit.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much for all the help. I'm now having the same problem with `tiny-expand`. See addition above.

Comment: @incandescentman updated for `tiny-expand`