# Warning (yasnippet): modified buffer in a backquote expression

Tags: yasnippet

When I use yasnippet, I keep getting this error:

```
Warning (yasnippet): `foo-snippet' modified buffer in a backquote expression.
To hide this warning, add (yasnippet backquote-change) to `warning-suppress-types'.
```

I added this line to my config:

```
(setq warning-suppress-types (quote ((\(yasnippet\ backquote-change\)))))
```

But it doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`warning-suppress-types` is a list defined in the `warnings` package.  You first need to load this package with:

```
(require 'warnings)
```

and after this, add the warning using `add-to-list`:

```
(add-to-list 'warning-suppress-types '(yasnippet backquote-change))
```

Comment: I added that line but I'm getting an error: http://dixit.ca/stackexchange/backquote.html

Comment: This is the error I get: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable warning-suppress-types)
  (member (quote (yasnippet backquote-change))`

Comment: What version of emacs are you on?

Comment: GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1404.47)

Comment: Apologies, I have no idea what's causing that for you -- that variable _should_ be baked in to Emacs after 22.1, by my understanding. What do you get if you remove that erroring line, start Emacs, and do `M-x describe-variable <ret> warning-suppress-types <ret>`?

Comment: I think this should be wrapped in `(eval-after-load 'warnings ...)`, or needs a `(require 'warnings)` first.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate answer is to fix `foo-snippet` so that it no longer modifies the buffer in backquote expression.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24062/5296 for some examples.

Also note that there was a bug causing yasnippet to issue this warning even when *other* buffers were being modified, so make sure you have the latest yasnippet (or else the current stable release (0.10) which doesn't have this warning at all).  See https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/716