# Insert current date with yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet

Since several years I've been using this snippet to insert a date into buffer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# name: date
# key: date
# --
`(insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d"))`$0
```

However nowadays I get this annoying warning:

```
Warning (yasnippet): `date' modified buffer in a backquote expression.
To hide this warning, add (yasnippet backquote-change) to `warning-suppress-types'.
```

This is clearly related to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24470/warning-yasnippet-modified-buffer-in-a-backquote-expression), but it is not clear what is the proper way to fix the snippet (rather then just suppress the message).

Comment: "the solution doesn't work" - do you mean the warning is not suppressed? It should be.

Comment: Sorry, that was poorly worded - I've updated it (plus your answer works so thanks again!)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should rewrite your snippet so that the backquoted expression doesn't modify the buffer, but instead returns the string to insert:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# name: date
# key: date
# --
`(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")`$0
```

For more examples, see [yasnippet truncates clipboard contents](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/yasnippet-truncates-clipboard-contents)