# Why does (indent-region ...) insert a 't' into my buffer?

Tags: indentation, yasnippet

I'm using this yasnippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name : case : {...}
# key: case
# --
`(indent-region (- (point) 20) (+ (point) 20) nil)`case ${2:constexpr}: ${3:\{}
    $0
    break;
${3:$(if (string-match "\{" yas-text) "\}" "")}
```

I think it's some default, but I'm not sure.  Until recently, this snippet worked fine, but now I get a `t` inserted into my buffer, and I think it comes from `(indent-region)`:

```
        break;
t      case constexpr: {

          break;
        }
      case
```

How do I get rid of this `t`?

Comment: What was in the buffer before you expanded the snippet, and how did you expand the snippet? There's nothing in indent-region that would insert a t, unless it's been changed from the normal definition.

Comment: Change it to `(progn (indent-region ...) nil)`.

Comment: Thank you politza, that helped. Apparently, there /is/ something in indent-region that would insert a t. Post your comment as an answer and I will happily accept it :)

Comment: My mistake, the last form of `indent-region` is `(setq deactivate-mark t)`, and `setq` does return its value. This is a (relatively) recent change to the function.

Comment: By the way, you should add `# expand-env: ((yas-also-auto-indent-first-line t))` to your snippet instead of trying to indent by side-effect like that.

Comment: If this is a recent change that's changed the behavior of `indent-region`, perhaps it's worth `report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong It's not a bug in Emacs, the bug is in the snippet depending on the return value of `indent-region`.

Comment: If `indent-region`'s return value changed from `nil` to something else, that's a change in the function's interface, which by definition is a breaking change. If it's not intended, it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks, npostavs, for the hint with # expand-env. I'm using this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of backquotes in a snippet is to insert the **value** of the form within the backquotes into the snippet expansion.  However, `indent-region` works by side-effect, and in recent Emacs versions happens to return `t`.  As politza suggested in the comments, you can use `(progn (indent-region ...) nil)` to drop the return value.

However, this still performs a side effect inside backquotes which will stop being supported in some future version (it triggers a warning in versions 0.11 and higher).  In this case, the indentation effect can be written much clearer by binding `yas-also-auto-indent-first-line`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name : case : {...}
# key: case
# expand-env: ((yas-also-auto-indent-first-line t))
# --
case ${2:constexpr}:${3: \{}
    $0
    break;
${3:$(if (string-match "\{" yas-text) "\}" "")}
```

This modification has just been accepted at https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/pull/176, and will come with the next yasnippet version (0.12), at least for MELPA packages which integrate snippets from that repo.  For other examples of avoiding side effects within backquotes, see [yasnippet truncates clipboard contents](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/yasnippet-truncates-clipboard-contents).